# Does curl-loader support HTTP 1.0?

Tags: http, testing

I am writing an automated test program using curl-loader, to send calculated requests to a client. I need to know if curl-loader supports HTTP 1.0, in order to code for a test case. In case it supports it, I'd like to know how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by asking in their mailing list itself. 
It seems it does not support HTTP 1.0 as of now, but they suggested a small change which might bring the support.
The change has not worked yet, so as of now there's effectively no support for HTTP 1.0.